# Can boolean be sent via HTTP POST at all?

Tags: php, http, post

I'm building a simple API in PHP, one of the body parameters must be a boolean (as per documentation), `true` or `false`. I'm using Postman to test, and it seems like I can't do it. Whenever I post `true` or `false` it is seeing it as strings. 0 or 1 does not work neither. What I am doing currently for this to work is something like this:

```
if($_POST['authenticate'] == 'true') {
            $_POST['authenticate'] = true;
        }
```

But this seems not right. Please point me in the right direction as I am not even sure now if it is possible to POST a boolean.

Comment: post variables will always be strings, its up to the other end to cast them

Comment: Form data/form-encoded data will be always string. PHP's [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ` can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP POST/GET variables will be converted into string associative arrays in PHP ($_POST $_GET). You will have to go through an explicit cast or re-assignment if you want to express the values as a different datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the problem implicitly - as in :

`if (isset($_POST["authenticate"]) { ... }`

In other words, don't POST `authenticate` if it is anyway to be `false`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$is_authenticate = filter_var($_POST['authenticate'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
```

Or:

```
$is_authenticate = $_POST['authenticate']=='true';
```